# What does setup.py do in Python's source file for python?

Tags: python, ssl, compilation, installation

I am trying to build a python from source using cross compilation. However, I was wondering what does the setup.py do inside the python source code. I was trying to include the _ssl module and it seems that setup.py is doing that. But for the directory inside the setup.py which python uses to look for ssl, is it relatively on the building machine or the target machine? Also, will setup.py used when I do import ssl in python?

Comment: Did you look at the source of the file? It looks to me as if the SSL files are looked for on the building machine. That makes total sense, as those files are needed for compilation.

Comment: Hi Pieters, thanks for your reply. I think you are right. I just did make install, and all the dependencies are moved to the includes or lib directory. After I move the whole installed package to the target platform, it just worked :-)